# PowerShell won't display my code

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am fairly new to PowerShell and I am wondering why when I run this code it skips everything and then goes straight to the pause?

Once I hit enter it does not display anything and closes the window.

To better explain what I am doing here. I am trying to connect remotely to a server in our network and check to see if specific processes are running. If they are not running the script will make them run.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong in PowerShell v3 on Windows 7 64bit?

```
$recall = Get-WmiObject win32_service -computername srv-95-obweb | Where {$_.name -eq 'Hyland Sch4'}
$sleeplab = Get-WmiObject win32_service -computername srv-95-obweb | Where {$_.name -eq 'Hyland Sch3'}

$date = Get-Date

if($recall.Status -eq 'Stopped') {
    Write-Host "Recall service is currently stopped and will be automatically started"
    Get-Service  '*Sch4' | Start-Service
    Write-Host "Recall service has been started $date"
} Else {
    if($recall.Status -eq 'Running') {
        Write-Host "Recall service is currently running"
    }
}

if($sleeplab.Status -eq 'Stopped') {
    Write-Host "Sleep Lab service is currently stopped and will be automatically started"
    Get-Service '*Sch3' | Start-Service
    Write-Host "Sleep Lab service has been started $date"
} Else {
    if($sleeplab.Status -eq 'Running') {
        Write-Host "Sleep Lab service is currently running"
    }
}

pause
```

Comment: By they way if I run it used powershell ISE and run them individually it works.

Comment: What is the value of `$recall.Status` and `$sleeplab.Status` when you run this and it doesn't work?

Comment: put `"A message"` at the end and see if it is written. If so, your conditionals (`if` checks) are probably never `$true`

Comment: I actually just changed it to .State.  Thank you for pointing that out.  It shows as "Running" but when I run the command it still goes straight for the pause.  Completely ignores the if statement.

Comment: Hello Orphid,  the message appears so the if statements must be false.  Any suggestion on how to turn them on?

Comment: I actually got it working by removing the second if statement after the else.

Answer (score 0):

The second if caused it to be false so it didnt post.  Also had the wrong propertie.  Making it .State instead of .status resolved the issue.  Thanks all for your help